# Color consecutive higher cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that color cells that are higher than the previous one. I want to color only cells that follow a serie of 5 cells each one hiher than the previous one.
In this screenshot, if I have such a series, only D14 should be colored in red, because D14>D13>D12>D11>D10>D9. 
In other terms, because from D9 to D13, the 5 cells are always higher than the previous one.

[image]

This is my code but it is not working:

```
Sub Consecutive_HigherCells()

Dim i, j As Integer

For j = 1 To 5

    If Cells (i,4).Value >> Cells(i-j,4).Value Then

    Cells(i, 4).Select

    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    End If

Next j

End Sub
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error somewhere?

Comment: I have 'Run-time error 1004' and this is not working.

Comment: What happens if D15 was 61? Would it also be coloured or does there have to be another run of 5?

Comment: 1.  Where's the `i` for loop, currently i = nothing as is declared a variant.  2. `>>` is not vba.  `>` will suffice.  3.  Unless `i` starts at 6 or higher you will need to stop the `j` loop before it reaches `i` or you will error.

Comment: what if you have 7 consecutive sorted elements...? will there be 2 colored cells?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the first candidate is cell **A6** *(since it has 5 predecessors)*:

```
Sub BetterRedThanDead()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 6 To N
        If boo(Cells(i - 1, 1), Cells(i - 2, 1), Cells(i - 3, 1), Cells(i - 4, 1), Cells(i - 5, 1)) Then
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function boo(a, b, c, d, e) As Boolean
    boo = False
    If a > b And b > c And c > d And d > e Then boo = True
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, 5 predecesors is an example, but I want to be able to use a code working for 1000 predecesor. How can I do so?

Comment: @Sylvain  Try replacing the ***boo()*** function with another function that uses a **For** loop over a specified range of cells.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to declare `i` variable. also `>>` is not the right way to compare values.

Line should be:

```
If Cells (i,4).Value > Cells(i-j,4).Value Then
```

Also you need to add something like

```
If j = 5 Then 'It implies your validation is success
 With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If
```