# Color last cells of a series of increasing cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that colors cells that are higher than the previous one. I want to color only cells that follow a series of 30 cells each one higher than the previous one. In this screenshot, if I have such a series, only E35 should be colored, because from E5 to E35, each of those 30 cells are strictly higher than their predecessor (E35>E34>E33>...>E6>E5).

[image]

This is the code I tried to do:

```
Sub Consecutive_HigherCells()

Dim i, j As Integer

For i = 32 to 10000
For j = 1 To 30

    If Cells (i,5).Value > Cells(i-j,5).Value Then

    Cells(i, 5).Select

    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    End If

Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Actually the code is not working because all cells from E32 until E1000 that are AT LEAST higher than one of the 30 premious cells are colored when I run it.

I really need your help

Comment: Why not update your last question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955969/color-consecutive-higher-cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option explicit

Sub Consecutive_HigherCells()

Const LIMIT as long = 30

Dim i as long, j as long, Counter as long

For i = 32 to 10000

Counter = 0

For j = LIMIT to 1 step -1

If cells(i-j-1,"E").Value2 > cells(i-j,"E").value2 Then
Counter = counter + 1
Else
Exit for
End if

Next j

If counter = LIMIT then cells(i,"E").interior.color = rgb(255,255,0)

Next i

End Sub
```

Untested and written on mobile, sorry for bad formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will run through your full list and colour cells where the next one in sequence is of a lower value

```
Sub HighlightCells30()
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long, count As Long
    count = 0
    lr = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To lr
        count = count + 1
        If Range("E" & i + 1).Value < Range("E" & i).Value Then
            If i <> lr And count > 30 Then
                Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                count = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I didnt quite get what the batches of 30 was trying to achieve?
EDIT: Updated code based on Scotts explanation below

Comment: The OP wants where 30 numbers in a row are greater than the one above not just the one above.

Answer (score 0):

@Chillin > Thanks for your help,  you were close. I modified your code and it is now working.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consecutive_HigherCells30()

Const LIMIT As Long = 30

Dim i As Long, j As Long, Counter As Long

For i = 32 To 10000

Counter = 0

For j = LIMIT To 1 Step -1

'If Cells(i - j - 1, "E").Value > Cells(i - j, "E").Value Then
If Cells(i - j - 1, "E").Value < Cells(i - j, "E").Value Then

Counter = Counter + 1
Else
Exit For
End If

Next j

If Counter = LIMIT Then Cells(i - 1, "E").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

Next i

End Sub
```